# remove string and brackets if string contains specific string. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to figure out how to remove string and brackets if a column have contains a certain string.

So in my column I can have two strings that contain brackets like this

```
col a
this is the text(text it is) and other information (COO: warning) some other information
```

What I can do is remove all text and brackets. But how do I just remove the string and brackets that contains COO: ??

```
cork_ing['DS VALUE Check'] = cork_ing['DS_VALUE'].str.replace(r"\(.*?\)","")
```

Can I modify the above code line just to remove and string with COO: ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could target terms in parentheses which only also contain the text `COO`, e.g.

```
cork_ing['DS VALUE Check'] = cork_ing['DS_VALUE'].str.replace(r'\([^)]*COO.*?\)', '')
```

Explanation of regex pattern:

```
\(     match literal (
[^)]*  then match zero or more non ) characters
COO    match 'COO'
.*?    match remaining content up until the first
\)     literal closing )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cork_ing['DS VALUE Check'] = cork_ing['DS_VALUE'].apply(lambda string: string.replace("(","").replace(")","") if "COO" in string else string)
```